# Cancel modifications that occured on a shelve

Tags: python, shelve

Modifications made on a shelve are saved at the end of the script even if methods close() and sync(). I would like to know if there is a way to avoid that pattern. In my case, I'm working on a small application to edit some datas. At the end, I ask user if he want to save modifications. If the answer is 'no' I don't want to synchronize the shelve.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is small enough to keep in memory, copy it to a normal dict first and only copy it back if they want to save their changes.

If it's too big, then depending on your application, you may be able to copy just a portion.

Comment: If it's the only way, I will do it like this. I was hoping that a method like 'clearCache' could exist.